# How to track DHL in our site from DHL site , by PHP

Tags: php

I went to [DHL online shipment tracking](http://www.dhl.com.vn/publish/vn/en/eshipping/track.high.html) 
and saw the form submit.

I want to include it on my site.
How can I do it with php?

Comment: If their terms of use allow automated tracking, they would provide an API for this.

Comment: @Col Shrapnel - which they did. Check out the DHL API specification at http://www.dhl-usa.com/xml/index.asp.

Comment: for german dhl tracking, just use the official module an choose "dhl intraship" as tracker. module: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/dhl-intraship-7494.html

Answer (score 3):

Here is the link from where you can get idea regarding DHL tracking using DHL API

http://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/serviceval/jsps/main/Main_menu.jsp

```
<?php
$data = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<req:KnownTrackingRequest xmlns:req="http://www.dhl.com" 
                        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.dhl.com
                        TrackingRequestKnown.xsd">
    <Request>
        <ServiceHeader>
            <MessageTime>'.date('c').'</MessageTime>
            <MessageReference>1234567890123456789012345678</MessageReference>
            <SiteID>YOUR_SITE_ID</SiteID>
            <Password>YOUR_PASSWORD</Password>
        </ServiceHeader>
    </Request>
    <LanguageCode>en</LanguageCode>
    <AWBNumber>7070000000</AWBNumber>
    <LevelOfDetails>ALL_CHECK_POINTS</LevelOfDetails>
</req:KnownTrackingRequest>';

$tuCurl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/XMLShippingServlet");
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_PORT , 443);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($tuCurl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: text/xml","SOAPAction: \"/soap/action/query\"", "Content-length: ".strlen($data)));

$tuData = curl_exec($tuCurl);
curl_close($tuCurl);
$simple = $tuData;
$xml = simplexml_load_string($tuData);
print"<pre>";
print_r($xml);
?>
```

Comment: I'm desperate to know how did you got that AWBNumber sample. I've tried every single sample number they provide in their crappy documentation/samples and none worked. However, this one works.

Comment: You can get some sample AWBNumber from (http://xmlpitest-ea.dhl.com/serviceval/jsps/main/Main_menu.jsp) Tracking -> XMLPI -> Sample XML's